# Simple image upload in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

Can anyone give me snippet of image upload in spring mvc ? I use @requestparam to get string and other data. But I want to get image and path of "web" folder..so I can save file there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  I understand well, you need to upload image file from the client to be sent in your request (Rest Controller) using the Spring MVC, so you can use spring form like this:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/spring-mvc-xml/uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="file">Select a file to upload</form:label></td>
        <td><input type="file" name="file" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

the most important part is to add the **enctype="multipart/form-data"** and the type of the **input must be** **"file"**, then you can add for your rest controller the multipart param like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, ModelMap 
modelMap) {
 // here u can find your uploaded file
return "fileUploadView";
}
```

finally you need to crate multipart Bean in your spring context like this:

```
//you can defined it in xml way if your configuration in xml file 

@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver()
{
 CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
   multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(20848820);
 return multipartResolver;
}
```

and also you need to add the upload file library at your dependency to Spring can use it :

```
dependency>
 <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
 <version>1.3.1</version> // or you can find the last version
</dependency>
```

I usually use this way to upload files in my Spring applications , so I hope that you are need also.